# How can I enter text and render the html using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to bind a text box to an angularjs variable and have it output rendered html in a separate div.

I have:

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
<form:textarea ng-model="ddata" id="displayData" path="displayData"/>

<div ng-bind-html-unsafe='ddata'>
{{ddata}}
</div></div>
```

and all I see is "{{ddata}}"

I would like to type in something like:
    'b bold text /b>

and have it render bold text.

If someone could post a fiddle, I would appreciate it greatly.

Comment: Have you wired up the rest of your app?

Comment: How do you mean?  As in, have I added the ng-app="myapp" directive to a containing div?  Yes.  I've also included the scripts for angular min and angular sanitized.  Or is there something else?

Comment: You're missing your own JS that says angular.module("myapp", []) most likely

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Version that works in angular < 1.2

http://jsfiddle.net/AQWAR/

The HTML

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
<form>
    <input type="text" ng-model="ddata"/>
</form>
{{ddata}}

<div ng-bind-html-unsafe='ddata'>
</div>
</div>
```

The JS

```
angular.module("myapp", []);
```

Version that works in Angular > 1.2 (specifically tested with 1.2.1)

http://jsfiddle.net/AQWAR/1/

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<form>
    <input type="text" ng-model="ddata.someString"/>
</form>
{{ddata}}

<div ng-bind-html='ddata.trustedVersion'>
</div>
</div>
```

The JS

```
angular.module("myapp", []).controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope","$sce", function($scope, $sce){
    $scope.ddata = {someString:"", trustedVersion:""}
    $scope.$watch("ddata.someString", function(newVal){
        $scope.ddata.trustedVersion = $sce.trustAsHtml(newVal);
    },true);
}]);
```

For some safer options check out $sanitize and $sce

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.$sanitize

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce

Comment: That's it.  Thank you.  I totally forgot the js.

Comment: Works with Angular 1.1.1, not 1.2.1.

Comment: Thanks Garry you're right with 1.2.1 you need to use ng-bind and $sce service to mark the data as trusted, I'll make an updated fiddle and update the answer.

Comment: @Garry updated the fiddle and the code above to reflect the changes needed.  I used $sce to explicitly trust the input, in application this may not be a great idea since it could potentially allow someone to inject code that will be run in the browser (cross site scripting).  So use with caution.

Comment: @shaunhusain Thanks for the update. $sce.trustAsHtml was the approach I took.