# angularjs: How to get text exactly same as in enter in text area, including new line?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In angularjs, how to get the exact text as entered into `html textarea`, I want to also track newlines, `'\n'` (in the textarea). I want to **store this textarea into database** exactly the same as entered into textarea. But it is taking all text into one line.

How do I detect that new line is inserted into html-area?

[Please see the demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/5p4aVChMpGhM5w5klSZY?p=preview)

I can use `<pre> {{someText}}</pre>`, but this will not solve my problem, Because I want to store into database.

```
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <label >Location Based Address </label>
             <textarea rows="4" cols="25" class="form-control" ng-model="someText"> 
             </textarea>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17794269/4759033

Comment: I don't get what is wrong. If you bind your ng-model to a textarea, you will have '\n' characters in, so you will have the lines in your text. Can you check in your debogguer the content of the data that send your client to your server. This maybe a server-side problem. Just saw your edit with the plunkr : this plunkr is just a textarea, there is no information about what is wrong in.

Answer (score 1):

I belive that the model does save newlines and such, see [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/NtUHIsfInXruOuz02dU7?p=preview) small edit on your plunkr, using a `<pre>` tag to display the data.

Also, when I save data to my SharePoint list, in a 'rich text' field, it saves newlines. I think your problem is that the server doesn't preserve the new lines.

Comment: @user1308874 yeah, I know this wasn't really an answer, but I felt it was too long to comment it. I'm helping you search for solution though, So I'll update if I find anything useful

Answer (score 1):

Please check i have edited your plunker code. [Check updated code](http://plnkr.co/edit/SJnPKyEisHDxqv81ELbY?p=preview)

```
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize'])

  .controller('SomeController', function($scope,$sce) {
    console.log($scope.someText);
    $scope.$watch('someText', function(){
      console.log($scope.someText);
      $scope.text = $scope.someText;
            $scope.text = $scope.text.replace(/\n\r?/g, '<br />');
        $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.text)
    })
  })
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace spaces with `\n` and store it that way, but I'm not sure how 'strong' this solution will be.

Answer (score 0):

Value from the textarea is passed as is to `someText` via `ng-model="someText"`. You don't need to do anything with the text as you can see in console.

If you want to print the value somewhere on your page while keeping new lines as the user entered them use `<pre>` tag:

```
<pre>{{ someText }}</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks martin, but I don't want to print anywhere but want to store into database, including the new line character..

Comment: I know you want to save it to the database. It's not a problem, new line characters are in the string as expected so storing in in a database won't machnge anything

Answer (score 0):

Well i'm not really sure of what is happening but i'll try a wild guess of all things that can happens :

1. When using textarea, \n characters are stored in the value of the ng-model.
2. If you want to display them either use <pre> or replace all \n by 
    and use ng-bind-html (https://docs.angularjs.org/#!/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)
3. If you want to send them to the server through json you may have to escape \n to \n same when sending data from the server to the client. Or it will be the underlying layers off your framework that will do it.
4. Make sure you're working with UTF-8 server-side/database or you may have problems with \r\n and \n.